# Flutter inspector with different engine

Tags: flutter

In my native android application, I use two flutter engines, both are used for FlutterFragment. When I run flutter inspector, I always see only one widgets tree - from the first FlutterFragment. How can I specify in flutter inspector which flutter engine/FlutterFragment to analyse?